# Automate a periodical "Minimize Memory usage" on Firefox

Tags: firefox, memory, performance, firefox-quantum

During many years using Firefox and forks and I've realized that sometimes Firefox gets slow and sometimes unresponsive.

Workaround, going to about:memory, and clicking on "Measure" button you can see how much memory is in use. However some of this memory should be free (related to closed tabs and ghosts)

At the moment this issue at least is active on Waterfox and i am freeing memory manually, but it is annoying to feel the lack of performance and then time consuming to do the steps.

How can be executed the function "Minimize Memory usage"?
Can the execution of this function be scheduled?

Though described issue maybe is not impacting on modern and official firefox, the question can apply to any firefox version.

Comment: There are add-ins to bookmark tabs and unload them, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/onetab/ , or see https://www.itechtics.com/2-ways-reduce-firefox-memory-usageleakage/ for settings to reduce usage.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox currently offers automatic unloading of "low priority" tabs when system memory is low.  You can see this by typing `about:unloads`.  This feature can be toggled via `browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory` on the `about:config` page.

You can read more about it [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/browser/tabunloader/) and [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/10/tab-unloading-in-firefox-93/)

Comment: `about:unloads` is the correct form. `browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory` is set to `false` by default, so I have changed that.

Comment: I am seeing that it is a new feature starting with Firefox 93.

Comment: @cipricus  Thanks for the correction. I've fixed that